# Mailchimp API send call returns Campaign_EgpPrediction error

Tags: mailchimp

I'm using MailChimp v2.0 API at the moment to replicate, update and then send mail campaigns. All so far so good, but occasionally I'm getting this curious error when I call campaigns/send

{
    "status": "error",
    "code": -99,
    "name": "Campaign_EgpPrediction_Exception",
    "error": "Campaign_EgpPrediction"
}

If I try again, it may work. Seems sporadic.

Workflow: I replicate one of our standard campaigns then get the new ID, then with this ID I update the title, make it a URL-driven campaign by updating the url value, move it to a folder, then send it.

All the other API calls are successful, just the send *sometimes* says that.

I can't find reference to the error anywhere in MailChimp docs, I have asked their API support team but whilst I'm waiting...

Comment: Updates as they occur, this from MC API Support which at least defines the problem:

"To provide some clarification, EGP is an automated system that predicts bounce rates and issues warnings in the event a high prediction is determined. The error message seen here looks like EGP predicted a higher than normal bounce rate for this specific campaign send."

I'm now approaching the compliance team for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a predicted bounce rate warning. After I went ahead and sent the campaign despite the warning (which doesn't exist in MailChimp's documentation) I got the following from the compliance team shortly afterwards:

> This is a note from the MailChimp compliance team. Omnivore, our automated abuse prevention system, detected a recent campaign that generated a bounce rate which exceeded allowable industry thresholds. Noting the account received an above threshold bounce rate, Omnivore has detected that this list requires removal from our system before we would be able to reactivate the account.
>
> As a bulk delivery service we are required to enforce the industry thresholds that ISPs, anti-spam groups and corporate email protection services set regarding spam complaints, bounces and unsubscribe requests. When rates exceed industry thresholds, as your campaign did, Internet Service Providers can block service to the entire MailChimp ecosystem.
>
> Keeping this in mind, the list must be removed from the account before we are able to support further sending. Because a list cannot be deleted for 7 days following a campaign send, we do ask that these contacts be bulk unsubscribed from the list following the instructions provided

So, it looks like the system will warn you with this error message via then API and then let's you send it anyway if you persist!

I hope this helps someone else in the future from sending to a list that may cause you larger problems later.